# C++ Placement new and Constructor call

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, allocator

I am learning the C++ placement new by the following code.

```
class Cell {
  public:
    Cell() {
      printf("default constructor by %s\n", __func__);
    }
    Cell(int ina) : a(ina) {
      printf("customized constructor.\n");
    }
    ~Cell() {}
    void* operator new(size_t);                             // Operator new.
    void* operator new(size_t, Cell*p) {
      return p;
    }
  private:
    int a;                                                  // tmp variable.
};

// Global variable.
Cell global_cell;

void* Cell::operator new(size_t size) {
  printf("start running the placement new\n");
  Cell* ptr = new (&global_cell) Cell;
  printf("the cell pointer is %p and the global address is %p\n", ptr,    &global_cell);
  return ptr;
}


int main() {
  printf("====\n");
  Cell *ptr = new Cell;
  printf("====\n");
}
```

Here is the output I got:

```
default constructor by Cell
=====
start running the placement new
default constructor by Cell
the cell pointer is 0x60107c and the global address is 0x60107c   
default constructor by Cell
=====
```

I know the first "default constructor" comes from the initiation of `global_cell`. But why I got two "default constructor" after that? Am I missing something about the placement new? Also, how can I implement the placement new with the second non-default constructor which takes an input integer?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo when I try to edit the post manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're implementing the custom `operator new` for the class in the wrong way.

`operator new` for a class should just provide the raw memory where to put the instance, not create an object. Placement new instead initializes an object (using the default constructor in your case because you specified no parameters).

If you want to use placement new and passing parameter just write

```
new (memory_address) MyObject(arg1, arg2);
```

but note that using placement new is sort of an *alternative* to defining a custom `operator new` for the class. In the latter you just call normal allocation with

```
new MyObject(arg1, arg2);
```

to use your custom allocator (that however should just provide enough and properly-aligned memory).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just figured it out the only thing I have to do is to return the memory address. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
new (&global_cell) Cell
```

in your `operator new` overload is one default construction, `new Cell` in `main`is the other.

`operator new` is only supposed to allocate memory, not construct an object; the relevant constructor is called automatically afterwards.

Using placement new with your non-default constructor isn't very complicated:

```
new (&global_cell) Cell(2)
```

(That is, there's no difference to "regular" `new`.)

Answer (score 0):

You get them when you call "new Cell":

```
Cell *ptr = new Cell;
Cell* ptr = new (&global_cell) Cell;
```

After operator new is called, constructor is always called